# PHP - Google Distancematrix returning result locally but not on webserver

Tags: php, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to access the google API and pull in some data, which is fine, although once I upload onto my webserver I don't get any output, which is strange because it works locally.

```
function distance() {

  $url = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=Vancouver+BC|Seattle&destinations=San+Francisco|Victoria+BC&mode=bicycling&language=fr-FR&sensor=false';
  $data = @file_get_contents($url);

  echo $data;

}

  distance();
```

I've tried using it with an API key also, but still having no luck.

Comment: What does firebug says about the requests?

Comment: Firebug doesn't give any output

Answer (score 0):

Typically it will work locally but not on your webserver because Google [doesn't require an API key for development on localhost](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-google-apis/wiki/MapsGettingStarted):

> Note that in order to use the Maps API version 2, you need to apply
>   for a Google Maps API key. Running with no key specified will work
>   with localhost for development purposes, but you will need to apply
>   for your own key to deploy to a website.

The API key is definitely absent from your code and it will behave exactly as you described.

You mention that you tried it with an API key as well but you don't go into details. Keep in mind that an API key is tightly tied to a particular website so you may need to [apply for a new API key](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/signup.html) for what you're doing.

> A single Maps API key is valid for a single "directory" or domain.

Note that a key for `www.example.com` will not be valid for `example.com`

Look at [this page](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/faq.html#keysystem) for more caveats with the API key.

Comment: I didn't add the API key within my code for obvious reasons, although even having added &key=code here, it still doesn't work.

I don't even get a REQUEST_DENIED error when using the key, so leads me to suggest it's supposedly working?

Comment: What version of the API are you using? V3 handles keys differently. If you're using v2, what domain did you generate your key on and what domain are you running your page on?

Comment: I think it's running version 2, I'm just using the webserver call, isn't v3 javascript only?